# How can I edit a specific value deep in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following JavaScript object in node:

```
that.responseData = {
    fields: {
        id: {
            label: 'ID',
            value: objectRecord.id,
            info: '',
            example: '',
            required: false,
            errorStatus: '',
            errorMessage: ''
        },
        title: {
            label: 'Title',
            value: objectRecord.title,
            info: '',
            example: 'The Best of C#',
            required: true,
            errorStatus: '',
            errorMessage: ''
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to easily change e.g. the `errorMessage` of a certain field, e.g. with:

```
this.setDataInFields('title', 'errorMessage', 'Title is required.');
```

What is the syntax to do this, e.g. if I have this function:

```
setDataInFields(idCode, property, value) {
    this.responseData.fields.author.errorMessage = 'changed'; // this works

    //this.responseData[idCode][property] = value; //doesn't work

    //this.responseData.fields = { //doesn't work
    //  [property]: value
    //};

    //this.responseData.fields[idCode][property]['errorMessage'] = value; // doesn't work
}
```

Comment: You can access them using either square brackets, or literal notation, but it would throw an error if parent node is undefined.

Comment: `//this.responseData.fields[idCode][property]['errorMessage'] = value; // doesn't work` - of course it doesn’t, because `property` is `errorMessage`, so you’d be trying to access a property `errorMessage` _of_ the `errorMessage` object here (but that is a string.)

Comment: is it assumed that you know the json metadata and expected field contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 this.responseData[idCode][property] = value; //doesn't work
```

You're almost there. You forgot to enter inside the `fields` key :

```
this.responseData.fields[idCode][property] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good option to use `lodash` to access deep objects as it might throw an error if something is undefined

```
let field = `fields.` + idCode + '.' + property
_.set(this.responseData, field, value)
```